# text editor that starts out in view mode?

Tags: text-editor

I would like a text editor that works like the Google Docs app, where you start out viewing a file and if you want to edit it you specifically have to click an "Edit" button.  The reason this would be useful is that the keyboard pops up automatically if you are editing text.  90% of the time, I simply want to view the text file and not make changes.  Or maybe I want to view the file and decide if I want to make changes after I see it.  Dismissing the keyboard or being prompted to save the file every time is annoying when I only wanted to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MiniNoteViewer (https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.gr.java_conf.hatalab.mnv&hl=en) basically works the way I want.  There's no explicit switch between "Edit" and "View" modes, but it doesn't pop up the keyboard until you tell it to.  Good enough.

Also Jota View (https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.sblo.pandora.jota) can be set to not pop up the keyboard when you are viewing a note (Preferences->Input->Viewer), though the app is overcomplicated IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Google docs](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs&hl=en) in your Android device.
Also you can use an editor called [INKPAD](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.workpail.inkpad.notepad.notes&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS53b3JrcGFpbC5pbmtwYWQubm90ZXBhZC5ub3RlcyJd), that works your way, the keyboard only is showed if you want to edit the note.

Comment: Thanks but I'm specifically looking for an editor for .txt files, typically files I've downloaded from my Dropbox account.  I don't think either Google Docs or Inkpad can view .txt files.

Comment: Google Docs can import .txt files.

Comment: Also you can see
https://market.android.com/search?q=dropbox&so=1&c=apps